# Current Browser version doesn't support with robot framework

Tags: google-chrome, pycharm, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework. I have used chrome version  93.0.4577.82 until yesterday and the code was working for that version. But, when I try to run the test today, it shows the following error message.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

### Setup failed:
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 92
Current browser version is 94.0.4606.54 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is raised when the Chrome and the Chrome driver version mismatch. 
This means that your Chrome version is 94 and the Chrome Driver is 92.
Chrome has probably updated itself, so you should update the ChromeDriver version downloading (and installing) a new one (94). 
Here the [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=94.0.4606.41/)